# Постоянное отслеживание событий jquery

Tags: jquery, javascript

При смене состояния формы select, отслеживание срабатывает только раз. Фишка в том, чтобы при смене на `select` с `option value=2` был запрет на ввод кирилицы, в текстовое поле.

Беда в том, что если выбрать другой option select, то запрет на ввод все равно остается

http://jsfiddle.net/Ga4Z5/

HTML

```
<div>
    <select id="services_id">

                <option value="1">One</option>
                <option value="2">Two</option>
                <option value="3">Three</option>
                <option value="4">Four</option>

</select>
</div>

<textarea id="text_mes_area" rows="5">

</textarea>
```

JavaScript

```
$(function () {
  $('#services_id').on('change', function () {
      var value = $("#services_id option:selected").val();
      if (value == 2) {
          $('#text_mes_area').bind('keyup', function () {
              $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[А-Яа-я]/i, ""));
          });
      }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если выбран другой вариант - снимайте обработчик с textarea:

```
if (value == 2) {
    $('#text_mes_area').on('keyup', function () {
        $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[А-Яа-я]/i, ""));
    });
} else {
    $('#text_mes_area').off('keyup');
}
```

Comment: точно) спасибо